# Удивительное поведение in_array

Tags: php

В процессе кодинга на PHP 7.4 неожиданно обнаружил совершенно нелогичное поведение функции in_array()

```
$parameter = "RITY";
$value = "hfg";

if( $parameter === "RITY" && ! in_array($value, [0, 1]) ) 
echo 1;
else
echo 2;
```

Этот код выдаёт 2! Если кто-то не верит - проверьте на https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/
При том что массив содержит только 0 и 1, а в $value произвольная строка - код ведёт себя так, как будто элемент "hfg" есть в массиве [0, 1]
Как это объяснить???

Answer (score 2):

Функция [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php) имеет такую сигнатуру:

```
in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] ) : bool
```

> Если третий параметр strict установлен в TRUE, тогда функция
> in_array() также проверит соответствие типов параметра needle и
> соответствующего значения массива haystack.

Соответственно, в вашем примере не происходит сравнения типов. Строка `hfg` будет преобразовываться в целое число. Из [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> Если строка распознается как числовое значение, результирующее
> значение и тип определяется так, как показано далее.
>
> Если строка не содержит какой-либо из символов '.', 'e', или 'E', и
> значение числа помещается в пределы целых чисел (определенных
> PHP_INT_MAX), строка будет распознана как целое число (integer). Во
> всех остальных случаях она считается числом с плавающей точкой
> (float).
>
> Значение определяется по начальной части строки. Если строка
> начинается с верного числового значения, будет использовано это
> значение. Иначе значением будет 0 (ноль). Верное числовое значение -
> это одна или более цифр (могущих содержать десятичную точку), по
> желанию предваренных знаком с последующим необязательным показателем
> степени. Показатель степени - это 'e' или 'E' с последующими одной или
> более цифрами.

Т.е. `$value` будет преобразовано в `0`. А это значение в массиве есть.

Чтобы исправить ситуацию, достаточно вызывать функцию так

```
in_array($value, [0, 1], true)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В моём случае - это усложняет ситуацию, т.к. извне (из JS) $value обычно приходит как тип string, в т.ч. и числа - их вводит юзер. Следовательно при $value = "1" я опять получаю нерабочий скрипт. В PHP принудительно приводить их к типу int тоже не вариант, т.к. в зависимости от переменной $parameter, в $value могут быть как числа, так и текст. Придётся лепить много условных операторов. Я много лет думал что in_array работает так: in_array($value, [0, 1]) будет давать true для $value = 0, 1, "0", "1" И так оно и должно работать по нормальной логике, а в реальности просто ДИЧЬ!

Comment: Поразительно, но обходной путь тоже не подчиняется законам нормальной человеческой логики. 
if( $parameter === "RITY" && !($value == 0 || $value == 1) ) 
также выдаёт 2! Оказалось, что if("dsgd" == 0) это true

Comment: Мозг упорно отказывается осознавать что это правда, после 10 лет кодинга мои незыблемые аксиомы о PHP полностью разгромлены.

Comment: Конечно, об этом в ответе и речь. При нестрогом сравнении строка приводится к числу. Используйте https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-numeric.php. PHP — слабо типизированный язык.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Выход здесь только один: всегда и везде использовать оператор строгого сравнения и напрямую, и в функциях, там где это возможно.
Навсегда забыть про оператор нестрогого сравнения - можно поймать очень трудноуловимые ошибки, особенно в большом коде.